# How to detect object from video using SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is my code for training the dataset of for example vehicles , when it train fully , i want it to predict the data(vehicle) from video(.avi) , `how to predict trained data from video and how to add that part in it ?` , i want that when the vehicle is shown in the video it count it as 1 and cout that the object is detected and if second vehicle come it increment the count as 2

```
    IplImage *img2;
    cout<<"Vector quantization..."<<endl;
    collectclasscentroids();
    vector<Mat> descriptors = bowTrainer.getDescriptors();
    int count=0;
    for(vector<Mat>::iterator iter=descriptors.begin();iter!=descriptors.end();iter++)
    {
       count += iter->rows;
    }
    cout<<"Clustering "<<count<<" features"<<endl;
    //choosing cluster's centroids as dictionary's words
    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster();
    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);
    cout<<"extracting histograms in the form of BOW for each image "<<endl;
    Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat trainingData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    int k = 0;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint1;
    Mat bowDescriptor1;
    //extracting histogram in the form of bow for each image 
   for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
    for(i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
            {
              sprintf( ch,"%s%d%s%d%s","train/",j," (",i,").jpg");
              const char* imageName = ch;
              img2 = cvLoadImage(imageName, 0); 
              detector.detect(img2, keypoint1);
              bowDE.compute(img2, keypoint1, bowDescriptor1);
              trainingData.push_back(bowDescriptor1);
              labels.push_back((float) j);
             }
    //Setting up SVM parameters
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.gamma = 0.50625000000000009;
    params.C = 312.50000000000000;
    params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.000001);
    CvSVM svm;



    printf("%s\n", "Training SVM classifier");

    bool res = svm.train(trainingData, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), params);

    cout<<"Processing evaluation data..."<<endl;


    Mat groundTruth(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat evalData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    k = 0;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint2;
    Mat bowDescriptor2;


    Mat results(0, 1, CV_32FC1);;
    for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
      for(i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
         {
           sprintf( ch, "%s%d%s%d%s", "eval/", j, " (",i,").jpg");
           const char* imageName = ch;
           img2 = cvLoadImage(imageName,0);
           detector.detect(img2, keypoint2);
           bowDE.compute(img2, keypoint2, bowDescriptor2);
           evalData.push_back(bowDescriptor2);
           groundTruth.push_back((float) j);
           float response = svm.predict(bowDescriptor2);
           results.push_back(response);
         }



    //calculate the number of unmatched classes 
    double errorRate = (double) countNonZero(groundTruth- results) / evalData.rows;
```

`The question is`This code is not predicting from video , i want to know how to predict it from the video , mean like i want to detect the vehicle from movie , like it should show 1 when it find the vehicle from movie

**For those who didn't understand the question :**

I want to play a movie in above code

```
VideoCapture cap("movie.avi"); //movie.avi is with deleted background
```

Suppose i have a trained data which contain vehicle's , and "movie.avi" contain 5 vehicles , so it should detect that vehicles from the movie.avi and give me `5` as output

How to do this part in the above code

Comment: Is this a question, or are you telling us how to do it?

Comment: This is not predicting from video , i want to know how to predict it from the video , mean like i want to detect the vehicle from movie

Comment: Why don't you accept any of the given answers? would you like more explanations or something like that?

Comment: @GilLevi Because no answer solve my problem , answer is accepted when it solve the problem , your answer is not related to my question , your asking to do it in other way , this is not the answer , there are many other who did the same task with other ways , and 2nd answer is also not the answer to be accepted , he is just answering how to break the video into array of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your code setup

```
params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
```

it appears that you train your classifier with more than two classes. A typical example in traffic scenario could be cars/pedestrians/bikes/... However, you were asking for a way to detect cars only. Without a description of your training data and your video it's hard to tell, if your idea makes sense. I guess what the previous answers are assuming is the following:

You loop through each frame and want to output the number of cars in that frame. Thus, a frame may contain multiple cars, say 5. If you take the whole frame as input to the *classifier*, it might respond "car", even if the setup might be a little off, conceptually. You cannot retrieve the number of cars reliably with this approach.

Instead, the suggestion is to try a *sliding-window approach*. This means, for example, you loop over each pixel of the frame and take the region around the pixel (called *sub-window* or *region-of-interest*) as input to the classifier. Assuming a fixed *scale*, the sub-window could have a size of 150x50px as well as your training data would. You might fixate the *scale* of the cars in your training data, but in real-world videos, the cars will be of different size. In order to find a car of different scale, let's say it's two-times as large as in the training data, the typical approach is to scale the image (say with a factor of 2) and repeat the sliding-window approach.

By repeating this for all relevant scales you end up with an algorithm that gives you for each pixel location and each scale the result of your classifier. This means you have three loops, or, in other words, there are three dimensions (image width, image height, scale). This is best understood as a three-dimensional pyramid. "Why a pyramid?" you might ask. Because each time the image is scaled (say 2) the image gets smaller (/larger) and the next scale is an image of different size (for eample half the size).

The pixel locations indicate the position of the car and the scale indicates the size of it. Now, if you have an N-class classifier, each slot in this pyramid will contain a number (1,...,N) indicating the class. If you had a binary classifier (car/no car), then you would end up with each slot containing 0 or 1. Even in this simple case, where you would be tempted to simply count the number of 1 and output the count as the number of cars, you still have the problem that there could be multiple responses for the same car. Thus, it would be better if you had a car detector that gives continous responses between 0 and 1 and then you could find maxima in this pyramid. Each maximum would indicate a single car. This kind of detection is successfully used with corner features, where you detect corners of interest in a so-called *scale-space pyramid*.

To summarize, no matter if you are simplifying the problem to a binary classification problem ("car"/"no car"), or if you are sticking to the more difficult task of distinguishing between multiple classes ("car"/"animal"/"pedestrian"/...), you still have the problem of scale and location in each frame to solve.

Comment: what if i only want the frame that contain the car , and ignore other frames which contain the same image of car , because , when the car enter into the range of camera and until it leaves , it approx take 10-15 frames , so counter count them as 15 cars

Comment: Then you need to "follow" the car from frame to frame. This is called object tracking.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have for using images is written with OpenCV's C interface so it's probably easy to stick with that rather than use the C++ video interface.

In which case somthing along these lines should work:

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromFile("movie.avi");

IplImage *img = 0;
while(img = cvQueryFrame(capture))
{
       // Process image
       ...
}
```

Comment: Yes , i know this code , and i used  , but how to predict , like how to get answer like , yes its a vehicle so it count it as 1

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a sliding window approach. In each window, you should apply the SVM to get candidates. Then, once you've done it for the whole image, you should merge the candidates (if you detected an object, then it is very likely that you'll detect it again in shift of a few pixels - that's the meaning of candidates).

Take a look at the V&J code at openCV or the latentSVM code (detection by parts) to see how it's done there.

By the way, I would use the LatentSVM code (detection by parts) to detect vehicles. It has trained models for cars and for buses.

Good luck.

Comment: @GiLevi I already did my work using the above algorithm , i have not much time to start the work in a new way , btw you also need to provide the link for other users who may take interest in your answer

Comment: I'm not suggesting using a different method, I'm suggesting to implement a sliding window approach using the svm you trained.

Comment: @GiLevi i am searching on it , but not getting any good tutorial + code example to implement it in my work

Comment: Look at the answer below, he explains the sliding window approach.

You can take a look at the V&J code in openCV and use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need detector, not classifier. Take a look at Haar cascades, LBP cascades, latentSVM, as mentioned before or HOG detector.

I'll explain why. Detector usually scan image by sliding window, line by line. In several scales. In every window detector solve problem: "object/not object". It may give you rough results but very fast.  Classifiers such as BOW, works very slow for this task. Then you should apply classifiers to regions, found by detector.

Comment: Smorodov Right now my focus is on accuracy and detecting through video , speed is not my issue right now

Comment: As I remember, every BOW detect on whole image takes several seconds. Let assume you have 640x480 image 20 frames/sec. You scan in 4 scales. with step 4 pixel. Time estimation for processing 1 sec video: 640*480*20*4/16=307200 seconds if classifier performance is 1 detect per second. Can you wait?

Comment: Smorodov Abviously not :) but i am not getting any good example of sliding window code from the net , and am totally new to opencv

Comment: Can i do it by simply applying only SURF ?

Comment: No, I think you'd be better take a look at standard opencv samples, all detectors implemented in opencv works with sliding window. I know that cars detectors uses Haar cascades, and HOG, or as mentioned above latentSVM. But car detectoin is not so easy task. Because appearence depends on many factors. If you have good stable background image, you can try BGS library ( http://code.google.com/p/bgslibrary/ ), for first stage. Then simply count connected components (blobs).

Comment: Smorodov i removed the background in the first stage from the video , and now am going to detect the car in the second stage

Comment: Smorodov so do i need to remove all the code above and write new from start or just remove the Bow from above ? and do i need to remove svm to use latent svm ?

Comment: Ok, than you have window with object. Then get every frame, get subimage with object from this frame, and apply classifier (as we discussed before). You don't need evaluate or load it every frame, just apply it to new subimage. May be you'll need scale every test window to some constant size (e.g. 50x50) but then you need train classifier on images with size 50x50. You can estimate size of sample image as minimal image you can say is it car or no.

Comment: Yes , i change images in 50*50 and than train it using svm along with surf features

Comment: Ok, it may work. I do not expect high accuracy, but may be I'm wrong :)

Comment: Smorodov but the problem is same there `How to detect from video` , mean how to use `svm.prediect` with video

Comment: I think you need some experiments. It's hard to predict result of such programs in real world applications. Because it depends on many factors, such as implementation of modules, training set, camera model and so on. Try build application that get subimage and applies BOW to this subimage. Look in debugger results, then try improve you solution. It's not so hard to change detector/classifier to other one. They all have similar interfaces.