# How to train my data only once

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is my code , which i am using for train the dataset but whenever i run the code it again start vectorization and feature counting training etc , and it takes time every time whenever i start , i want it that it should train ones and not takes time again and again

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

    int i,j;
    IplImage *img2;
    cout<<"Vector quantization..."<<endl;
    collectclasscentroids();
    vector<Mat> descriptors = bowTrainer.getDescriptors();
    int count=0;
    for(vector<Mat>::iterator iter=descriptors.begin();iter!=descriptors.end();iter++)
    {
       count += iter->rows;
    }
    cout<<"Clustering "<<count<<" features"<<endl;
    //choosing cluster's centroids as dictionary's words
    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster();
    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);
    cout<<"extracting histograms in the form of BOW for each image "<<endl;
    Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat trainingData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    int k = 0;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint1;
    Mat bowDescriptor1;
    //extracting histogram in the form of bow for each image 
   for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
    for(i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
            {
              sprintf( ch,"%s%d%s%d%s","train/",j," (",i,").jpg");
              const char* imageName = ch;
              img2 = cvLoadImage(imageName, 0); 
              detector.detect(img2, keypoint1);
              bowDE.compute(img2, keypoint1, bowDescriptor1);
              trainingData.push_back(bowDescriptor1);
              labels.push_back((float) j);
             }
    //Setting up SVM parameters
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.000001);
    CvSVM svm;



    printf("%s\n", "Training SVM classifier");

    bool res = svm.train(trainingData, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), params);

    cout<<"Processing evaluation data..."<<endl;


    Mat groundTruth(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat evalData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    k = 0;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint2;
    Mat bowDescriptor2;


    Mat results(0, 1, CV_32FC1);;
    for(j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
      for(i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
         {
           sprintf( ch, "%s%d%s%d%s", "eval/", j, " (",i,").jpg");
           const char* imageName = ch;
           img2 = cvLoadImage(imageName,0);
           detector.detect(img2, keypoint2);
           bowDE.compute(img2, keypoint2, bowDescriptor2);
           evalData.push_back(bowDescriptor2);
           groundTruth.push_back((float) j);
           float response = svm.predict(bowDescriptor2);
           results.push_back(response);
         }
```

I just learn about the method to save the file of trained data like `train.xml` and than use it in prediction , but i am not clear about it and its use

Comment: So, save the training data into a file, and load that file next time round?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes , some thing like this , Is there any better approach than this ? for real time app

Comment: Depends on how the training data works. If it's ALWAYS the same data (or very rarely changes), then having a separate application that builds a "training data" file. If the training data is constant, then build a constant data set in "C++", and let the code use that. If it's likely to change from time to time, make it a file that is slurped in at startup - should be quicker than doing image analysis.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes its always the same data (and very rarely changes) , i am using it for detecting object from video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After training you need save SVM, it has method read and write, also you need to save vocabulary.

For using trained classifier you need load svm, and vocabulary. Then set vocabulary to descriptor extractor. Extract descriptors. Use SVM method predict.

Comment: Yes , i know about the function `sv.save("filename.txt/xml")` but why to save vocabulary and i evaluate my data in the last part so i need to save data before it ? or after it , and how to upload it predicting part ?

Comment: After saving that file , should i delete the / or not call the function , which train the data , and use the same `.txt` file which contain the data

Comment: You need save vocabulary (after train part) because it is used by BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE. Descriptors, evaluated by bowDe used for trained svm as input vector. Vocabulary is feature cluster centers, and they need for evaluation of bow histograms. So, you need train part run only once. If you get saved classifier and vocabulary, just load them and use. Each pair of files (svm,and vocabulary) is set for detection of one set object classes. For other set of object classes you need other pair of these files.

Comment: You want to say after this line :
`bool res = svm.train(trainingData, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), params);`
I should use :
`svm.save("res.txt");
svm.save("bowDe.txt");`

Comment: and after `Mat results(0, 1, CV_32FC1);` line , i should load both of these files ?

Comment: No, svm.save("res.txt"); but then you sould save matrix vocabulary: Mat t;
FileStorage f;
f.open("vocabulary.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
f << "vocabulary" << vocabulary;
f.release(); then set vocabulary bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);. In the beginning,  you sould check if files exists, and if it is, skip training phase. Load and setup data as described above.

Comment: Smorodov +1,All the code belong to voacbulary should save before this line bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary); ? which i already define in start ? and can you please give a look to my this question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172371/how-to-detect-object-from-video-using-svm'